# Creating a unique constraint on a column with a condition for uniqueness

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint, unique-index

Say I have a table containing 3 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL,
    some_boolean boolean DEFAULT TRUE
);
```

I want to create a unique constraint on the 'name' column, but it only has to be unique *out of all the ones that have `some_boolean = true`*. e.g. if I have an entry called `banana` that has `some_boolean` as `false`, I can create another also called `banana`.

**More specifically:** My table has an `expiration_date` column, I need the names to be unique out of all of the non-expired objects

Comment: Look up _filtered unique index_.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional unique constraint can be achieved using the conditional unique index as follows:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX some_table_Unq ON some_table (name) WHERE (some_boolean = TRUE);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fed237bfd89ff11c836a3daa5314d5a6)

You can replace `some_boolean = TRUE` with `some_boolean` and in your case with `expiration_date is null`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique filtering index like this:

```
create unique index idx_some_table_uniq_name 
    on some_table(name) 
    where (some_boolean);
```

Or if you want to filter on rows where `expiration_date` is `null`:

```
create unique index idx_some_table_uniq_name 
    on some_table(name) 
    where (expiration_date is null);
```